# Android adapter Not reading XML file

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I have a XML file named row.xml and I am trying to get my database to print out into the list view using the layout of the XML file (Two TextViews). But when i set my adapter layout layout to the row.xml file it isnt working. I am very new to android so i might be doing something silly. any help will be great!

row.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView android:id="@+id/item1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/item2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is the code i am using for my adapter and trying to call the xml file

```
    com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter db = new com.example.rory.dbtest.DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();

    ArrayList<String> data_list=new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
    if (c.moveToFirst())
    {
        do {
            data_list.add(c.getString(0));
            data_list.add(c.getString(1));
            //DisplayRecord(c);
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.row, data_list);
    lv.setAdapter(aa);
```

Comment: First off, you don't need if/do/while, all you need is while (Cursor is always positioned on the -1 row after a query). Now, are you sure you have data on Cursor?

Comment: yes my cursor is Cursor c = db.getAllRecords() and this is in my DB class where it returns all the rows

Comment: Print the strings on your cursor to logcat to make sure they have values.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that for each row in your result set, you want to create a String tuple that represents the row.  I'd make use of Android's Pair class.

You could do something like:

```
List<Pair<String, String>> data_list = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();

Cursor c = db.getAllRecords();
if (c.moveToFirst())
{
    do
    {
        data_list.add(new Pair<String, String>(c.getString(0), c.getString(1)));
        //DisplayRecord(c);
    }
    while (c.moveToNext());
}
```

And then define your ArrayAdapter like so (overriding getView to set your first and second TextView text correctly):

```
ArrayAdapter<Pair<String, String>> aa = new ArrayAdapter<Pair<String, String>>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.row, data_list)
{
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        TextView tvItem1 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item1);
        TextView tvItem2 = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.item2);

        Pair<String, String> itemAtPosition = getItem(position);

        tvItem1.setText(itemAtPosition.first);
        tvItem2.setText(itemAtPosition.second);

        return v;
    }
};
```

Comment: I was typing something like this... you posted it first... but I have the same opinion. good answer!

Comment: Thanks for the help Micheal! just as another question on the same topic, say if i added a button and edittext to the row.xml, how would i make it so that when the button is clicked the edittext will display a number? Would i have to us an onClickListener for each row?

Comment: That way will work.  Keep in mind that ListView uses a Flyweight pattern and recycles its views, so adding an OnClickListener on a button within your view layout will work, but you still need to match this up with the correct list item.  One way to do this is to use the setTag method of View to store the list position to which your button refers.   You can also set an OnItemClickListener on the ListView itself.  This will give you a click for the whole row, though.

Comment: I am trying to have two buttons on each row a '+' button and a '-' button and when clicked they will increment or decrement a number in a edit text on that row. So do you think setting a onclick listener for each button is still the better option?

Comment: also when i use the above code the screen remains blank, and i dont know why, any idea?

Comment: Did you call lv.setAdapter(aa)?